# Show that $\dbinom{2n}{n} + \dbinom{2n}{n-1} = \frac{1}{2} \dbinom{2n+2}{n+1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Show that $\dbinom{2n}{n} + \dbinom{2n}{n-1} = \frac{1}{2} \dbinom{2n+2}{n+1}$

> By induction, suppose that for some n its true,
>   $\dbinom{2n}{n} + \dbinom{2n}{n-1} = \dbinom{2n+2}{n+1}$ by theorem, but, I don't know how to prove that 
>   $\dbinom{2n+2}{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} \dbinom{2n+4}{n+2}$

Comment: If you write these binomials in terms of factorials and add through a common denominator, it will get you pretty far

Comment: $\dbinom{2n}{n} + \dbinom{2n}{n-1} = \dbinom{2n+2}{n+1}$?  Try this when $n=1$

Comment: $\dbinom{2}{1} + \dbinom{2}{0} = 3 =\frac{1}{2}  \dbinom{4}{2} =\frac{6}{2} =3$

Comment: When I write these binomials in terms and use some properties $\dbinom{2n+2}{n} + \dbinom{2n}{n-1} =\frac{1}{2}  \dbinom{2n+4}{n+2} \rightarrow \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{(2n+4)!}{(n+2)!(n+2)!}$ so I obtain that $\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!} = \frac{2n+3}{(n+2)} \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!}$ I don't know for what common denominator I have to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
{2n\choose n}+{2n\choose n-1}&=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}+\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(2n)!(n+1)}{n!(n+1)!}+\frac{(2n)!n}{n!(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(2n)!(n+1+n)}{n!(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(2n+1)!}{n!(n+1)!}\tag{1}
\end{align}$$
And
$$\begin{align}
\frac 12{2n+2\choose n+1}&=\frac 12\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac 12\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)!}{(n+1)n!(n+1)!} \\
&=\frac{2n+2}{2(n+1)}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(2n+1)!}{n!(n+1)!}\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Finally, combine $(1)$ and $(2)$. You can also use [Pascal's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) to immediately obtain the result in $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 2 red balls and other white. On how many ways you can choose $n+1$ of them? One answer is ${2n+2\choose n+1}$.

And second answer:

If both red are choosen then we must choose $n-1$ balls beetwen $2n$ balls, so that is $${2n\choose n-1}$$

If one red is choosen then we must choose $n$ balls beetwen $2n$ balls and one red, that is two ways, so that is $$2{2n\choose n}$$

If no red is choosen then we must choose $n+1$ balls beetwen $2n$ balls, so that is $${2n\choose n+1} =  {2n\choose n-1}$$

Sum that and you are done.